# gif files gives a 404 error in windows azure

Tags: iis, azure

i have deployed a `gif` file for the first time in my windows azure but its gives a 404 error , im sure that image paths are correct and **png** files within the same folder shows correctly

Is there any special configuration should be fixed with IIS in the remote machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no special configuration within IIS to serve GIF files.  Are you able to Remote Desktop to the machine and verify the files are correct (where you would expect them to be)?

Comment: thanks actually it was a path issue but still we are confused how that happened